# Error message using arrange function from Dplyr package in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set that I'm trying to rearrange in ascending order of one of the variables. I had to create a function to give the entries of the new variable which was done successfully but when I'm trying to arrange it, the console gives the following error:

> Error: incorrect size (1), expecting :1515

I've tried changing the way the new column was made and tried arranging again but it gave the same error again!

Here is the code I've wrote:

```
# Add a variable which gives the distance from the centre of leeds
# Begin by creating a function which will give the distance from the centre of leeds to location of accident

distance <- function(Grid.Ref..Easting, Grid.Ref..Northing, Centre.Easting = 429967, Centre.Northing = 434260){

  easting.difference <- abs(Centre.Easting - Grid.Ref..Easting)

  northing.difference <- abs(Centre.Northing - Grid.Ref..Northing)

  dif <- round(sqrt(easting.difference^2 + northing.difference^2),digits=2)

  return(dif)

}

# use this function to now create a new column which shows the distance of the accident from the cente of Leeds
accident4 <- mutate(accident3,

                    "Distance.from.centre.of.Leeds" = distance(Grid.Ref..Easting, Grid.Ref..Northing, Centre.Easting = 429967, Centre.Northing = 434260)
)

# arrange the data in order of distance from the centre of Leeds in ascending order

accident5 <- arrange(accident4, "Distance.from.centre.of.Leeds")
```

Comment: what happens if you remove quotes?

Comment: Don't understand why, but it works! Thank you!

Comment: look at `?arrange` and check out the examples, [this cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf) is also helpful